# React router using hash url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react. I would like to implement react router as hash url.
For Example I need a url #/list in react-router but by default react uses /list url. How can I implement hash url in react ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of a HashURL, by making use of HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter for your router config

```
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

render() {
    return <HashRouter>
         <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </HashRouter>

}
```

In case you are using a react-router v3 or lower, you would specify `hashHistory` to Router

```
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

render() {
    return <Router history={hashHistory}>
         <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Router>

}
```